# Отправка POST запроса, нюансы

Tags: php, java, android, http, post

Есть такой код:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "username"));      
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

вроде код робочий, но строки:
UrlEncodedFormEntity и execute у меня подчеркнуты красным..
В чем может быть проблема?
Никаких библиотек не подключал...
Может с импортом (import) чтото не так, или с манифестом..(не добавил чего..)?

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html

Comment: а можно пример того как это использовать? Можно пример с моим кодом.. Что мне добавить или поменять...

Comment: Нужно скачать библиотеку Apache HTTP Client и подключить ее. Далее вот пример https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html